# How to detect loop before adding child Node to parent Node Java

Tags: java

I have a Node model like below with list of child nodes:

```
class Node {
    private String name;
    private List<Node> childNodes;

    public Node(String name, List<Node> childNodes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.childNodes = childNodes;
    }

    public Node(String name) {
        this(name, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildNodes() {
        return childNodes;
    }

    public void setChildNodes(List<Node> childNodes) {
        this.childNodes = childNodes;
    }

    public void addChildNodes(Node childNode) {
        this.getChildNodes().add(childNode);
    }
}
```

What I am going to do is checking if a loop is produced when adding a child node to a parent node. Loop here means a child node has the same name as its direct or indirect parent. And when the loop is detected, I would like to print out also which nodes are content in this loop. What I have done sofar is:

```
    private static void findLoop(Node currentNode, String orginalNodeName, String visitedNode) {
        if (currentNode != null && !currentNode.getChildNodes().isEmpty()) {
            for (Node childNode : currentNode.getChildNodes()) {
                visitedNode = visitedNode + "->" + childNode.getName();
                if (childNode.getName().equals(orginalNodeName)) {
                    System.out.println("Loop is detected: " + visitedNode);
                }
                findLoop(childNode, orginalNodeName, visitedNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

My idea is looping through all the child nodes, start from the node that I want to check, and compare if the current node has the same name as the original starting Node, if yes then a loop is detected.

It works but I can not print the content of the loop correctly, because it loop through all of the possible child nodes of a parent node, ex:

```
            parentNode
    node1                node2
  childNode1           childNode2
                parentNode   childChildNode2
```

It printed: `parentNode->node1->node2->childNode2->parentNode` and what I would like to print is : `parentNode->node2->childNode2->parentNode`

Can anyone give me some hint here? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your solution has 1 weak point - it wont detect inner loops. For example if childChildNode2 has node2 as a children. I suggest you transfer all the chain of visited nodes to your method as argument and do check with whole chain

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pretty close to the result that you would like to get, here are several hints for you on how to complete the task:

- **`findLoop` needs to return `boolean`** - otherwise you would not know when to stop iterating at the higer levels of recursion
- **`visitedNode` needs to be a `List<Node>`** - otherwise you are stuck with a single item's name
- **When `findLoop` inside `for(...)` returns `true`, method returns `true` immediately** - this makes sure that a positive does not get ignored

Finally, don't forget that `findLoop` needs to start with the child node, and loop for the parent node, not the other way around.

Comment: Hi dasblinkenlight, thank you for your tipps. What I am getting stuck here is to print out all of the node that it has traversed. Like example above, the loop is detected when it goes from parentNode->node2->childNode2->parentNode, but as my implementation above, it will go through node1 and childNode1 before going to node2, no node1and childNode1 will also be in the traversed list which I would like to avoid.